# Are there buttons in a-frame and how to create them?

Tags: button, aframe

A question about a-frame? Does aframe offer button objects (like a-button)? If yes, why are there no information about them in the documentation?
Are they planned to be added?
And if it isnt, is there a way to create objects in a-frame that behave like button that can be used on a touchscreen?

Comment: You want a 3D button in the scene or an overlay UI ?

Comment: An overlay UI @PiotrAdamMilewski

Comment: then i'd go with html UI instead of 3D a-frame elements.

Comment: but the buttons have to be centered around a tracked image.
I cant see html UI working there @PiotrAdamMilewski

Comment: I may have an idea, I'll try to make something up tomorrow ;)

Comment: took me a bit longer, anyway, how about something in [this](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/arjs/tracked-ui/README.md) direction.

Comment: this is awesome. Thanks I will try it out today @PiotrAdamMilewski

Answer (score 0):

You can turn pretty much any a-frame object into a button.

1. make your cursors rayOrigin to your mouse. (You can add the cursor attribute to your camera)

```
<a-camera cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"></a-camera>
```

2. For example lets take an a-box primitive and turn it into a button by adding the standard onclick event to the element

```
<a-box onclick="doSomething"></a-box>
```

And initiate the function you want.
This should work for touch too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an overlay UI, I'd always go with HTML elements. They're easier to manage, as you can position them on the screen easily.

If you want the UI to track an object (like a marker in `arjs`), you can use my [tracked-ui](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/arjs/tracked-ui/README.md) component as follows:

```
<!-- The HTML UI -->
<div id="ui"></div>
<a-scene arjs>
   <a-marker tracked-ui="element: #ui; offset: 0 200">
     <a-box></a-box>
   </a-marker>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer but I still have on question with the UI: Can I use it to start or pause a video? I tried it now multiple times but it leads to an error? Do you ahve any idea where the problem comes from? https://github.com/Jorg313/ARJStest1/blob/main/Videotest.html

Comment: Something like [this](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/arjs/tracked-ui/video.html)?